# string interpolation in angular 2 and it's dynamicity

Tags: angular, string-interpolation, 2-way-object-databinding

In Angular2, why if i put a property in a simple view, like this:

```
<span>{{allowServer}}</span>
```

it change whenever its value change on its .ts file, and if i put it like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled={{allowServer}} >server</button>
```

the button doesn't get the new value disabled?

So, what is the rule for which I have to use interpolation instead of binding syntax?

```
[disabled]=allowServer
```

Answer (score 8):

### [prop]="value"

is for object binding to properties (@Input() of an Angular component or directive or a property of a DOM element).

### prop="{{value}}"

binds a value to a property. **The value is stringified** (aka interpolation)

See lets look at an example:

```html
<button id="button1" disabled={{allowServer}} >server</button>
<button id="button2" [disabled]={{allowServer}} >server</button>
```

**1) allowServer === true**

```typescript
button1.disabled = 'true' // string

button2.disabled = true   // boolean
```

**2) allowServer === false**

```typescript
button1.disabled = 'false' // string so disabled is true

button2.disabled = false// boolean
```

As you can see `button1` will always be `disabled`

[image]