# Pass parameter to child component Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, metronic

When I pass object to child component from parent - it comes converted to string

```
<m-tank-add fuelTypes="{{this.fuelTypes}}" count="{{count}}"></m-tank-add>
 @Input() fuelTypes: Array<FuelTypeModel>;
 @Input() count: number;
```

`count` comes as `"5"` and `fuelTypes` as `"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"`

How can I pass parameters so they wouldn't be converted to string?

Comment: @yurzui You should make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using property binding through square brackets since with interpolation value is stringified:

```
[fuelTypes]="fuelTypes"
```

See also:

- [string interpolation in angular 2 and it's dynamicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509364/string-interpolation-in-angular-2-and-its-dynamicity/46509519#46509519)